# How can I pass a function variable into a click event jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a function var into a click event. See the code below.Appreciate.

```js
function coolfunction(){
           var cool="hello";
  }

$('#good').on('click',function(){
             alert(cool);//how can i pass the function var here

  });
I am trying to pass a
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="good">click</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Local variables are only visible inside the function they're declared in. If you want a variable accessible outside, use a global variable instead.

Comment: can I create global variable inside the function?

Comment: Yes. If you assign a variable without using a `var` declaration, it assigns the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cool = '';

function coolfunction(){
     cool="hello";
}

$('#good').on('click',function(){
      coolfunction();
      alert(cool);//this will print "hello"
});
```

Comment: This won't alert anything.

Comment: What if I cannot put the function inside the click, do I have another option?

Comment: @conan what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of the function

```
$('#good').on('click', coolfunction);
```

then put the alert in coolfunction

```
function coolfunction(){
       var cool="hello";
       alert(cool);
}
```

If you don't want the alert in coolfunction, then return cool in coolfunction and use the return value.

```
function coolfunction(){
       var cool="hello";
       return cool;
}

$('#good').on('click', function() {
    var cool = coolfunction();
    alert(cool);
});
```